# Storing value of radio button in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I think this is very silly question but i didn't get it.Actually I am trying to get values of checked radio button and store all to local Storage but it is showing null.

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="radioMediators" style="display:none; float:left; margin-left:50px;margin-top:8px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="1">1 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="2">2
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="3">3 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="4">4 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="5">5
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P2" value="1">1 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P2" value="2">2
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P2" value="3">3 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P2" value="4">4 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P2" value="5">5
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P3" value="1">1 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P3" value="2">2
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P3" value="3">3 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P3" value="4">4 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P3" value="5">5
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P4" value="1">1 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P4" value="2">2
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P4" value="3">3 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P4" value="4">4 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P4" value="5">5
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P5" value="1">1 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P5" value="2">2
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P5" value="3">3 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P5" value="4">4 
                    <input type="radio" name="M1P5" value="5">5
                    </div>
```

And for storing purpose I am using this code:

```
var a1=localStorage.getItem($('input[name="M1P1"]:checked'));
```

Same for all(M1P2,M1P2,M1P3,M1P4,M1P5)

```
alert(a1);
alert(b1);
```

But this is showing null.
What I did wrong.Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code to set the items before accessing using `getItem()`? You have to use `setItem()` to save the values first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it and found that it was a very silly question.

```
localStorage.setItem('a_value',$('input[name="M1P1"]:checked').val());

alert(localStorage.getItem('a_value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i tried, i too am a noob here,

So am not sure whether its of any use for you or not, but i got the alerts ryt eventually :-p.

Here's what i did, added class to the radio buttons and remove style= display:none;

```
<div id="radioMediators" style="; float:left; margin-left:50px;margin-top:8px;">
    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="1" class='a'>1
    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="2" class='a'>2
    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="3" class='a'>3
    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="4" class='a'>4
    <input type="radio" name="M1P1" value="5" class='a'>5
```

and a bit modified the Jquery code:

```
// When the page is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a').click(function () {
        var b = 0;
        var c = 0;
        $('input[name="M1P1"]:checked').each(function () {
            b = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            var testobj = ('$(this)', b);
            c = localStorage.setItem('testobj', testobj);
        });
        alert(b);
        var a1 = localStorage.getItem('testobj');
        alert(a1);

    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="pSex" class="pe">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="rMale" onchange="localStorage.setItem('pSex', 'male');" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="rFemale" onchange="localStorage.setItem('pSex', 'female');"> Female<br> 
</form>
```